# How to use spring:message in a forEach loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been working on a system that provides bilingual support to a website from a database using the `<spring:message />` tag library.

I can read/write to the applications en/fr properties files. When I hardcode what would be a new key `<spring:message />` will display it correctly. Ex) `<spring:message code="f12345' />` will display "test data".

What I am having problems doing is using a dynamic key. No matter how I try to attach the key it fails.

Here are the methods I have tried group by end result.

500 error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: (line: [104], column: [29]) [quote/equal] symbol expected

- `<spring:message var><c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" /></spring:message>`
- `<spring:message var='<c:out value=\"${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}\" />" text="wrong" />`
- `<spring:message code="<c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" />" text="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" />`
- `<spring:message code=<c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" /> text="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" />`
- `<spring:message code= <c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" /> />`

Next we have the non-server crash which simply causes the table to not display

- `<spring:message var='<c:out value="application.message" />' arguments="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" />`
- `<spring:message var='<c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" />' text="wrong" />`
- `<spring:message code="<c:out value=\"${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}\" />"  />`
- `<spring:message code="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" />`
- `<spring:message code="messageCode" arguments="$value1}" />`
- `<c:set var="temp" > <c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" /> </c:set><td><spring:message code="messageCode" arguments="${temp}" htmlEscape="false" /></td>`

The best I have managed to get to simply displays the text of the key instead of the value. Which can already be done using `<spring:message text="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" />'`

In the applicationResources file

```
 messageCode=Test message for {0}.
```

Then inside the jsp page

```
 <c:set var="temp" > <c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" /> </c:set>
```

displays "Test message for CLUVALUE.C1111."

I found [one site](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/22361-form-select-problem) online which appeared to be doing the same thing.

```
<form:select path="${path}">
<c:forEach var="i" items="${items}">
<form:option value="${i[itemValue]}">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${localize}">
      <spring:message code="${i[itemLabel]}" text="${i[itemLabel]}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <c:out value="${i[itemLabel]}"/>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</form:option>
```

I have found a [second example](https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/How+to+Embed+HTML+Form+%28generated+by+HTML+Form+Entry+module%29+in+a+custom+module) where they have a dynamic key with the spring message being used in a forEach loop. Search for `spring:message` and its 14/17.

```
 <c:forEach items="${errors.allErrors}" var="error">
            <spring:message code="${error.code}" text="${error.code}"/><br/>
        </c:forEach>
```

I have found a [third example](http://javahonk.com/iterate-spring-mvc-error-message-on-jsp/).

In the three examples I have found, the `spring:message` are all used the same, with the code and text attributes being the same.

I cant see the output, and I cant be sure that their text argument isnt being displayed instead.

Here is the controller block

```
 List<CLU_STRUT> myCLUs = cluService.BuildCLUs();
 model.addAttribute("CommonLookUp", myCLUs);
```

And here is the JSP

```
<c:forEach var="CLUObject" items="${CommonLookUp}" varStatus="vs">
<tr>
    <c:set var="temp" > <c:out value="${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}" /> </c:set>
    <td><spring:message code="messageCode" arguments="${temp}" htmlEscape="false" /></td>
    <td><c:if test="${CLUObject.getCountNew() gt 0}"> <a href='drillview?drillvalue=${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}&mode=drill&drilltype=I'><c:out value="${CLUObject.getCountNew()}" /></a></c:if><c:if test="${CLUObject.getCountNew() eq 0}">0</c:if></td>
    <td><c:if test="${CLUObject.getCountMod() gt 0}"> <a href='drillview?drillvalue=${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}&mode=drill&drilltype=U'><c:out value="${CLUObject.getCountMod()}" /></a></c:if><c:if test="${CLUObject.getCountMod() eq 0}">0</c:if></td>
    <td><c:if test="${CLUObject.getCountDelete() gt 0}"> <a href='drillview?drillvalue=${CLUObject.SpringKey_name()}&mode=drill&drilltype=D'><c:out value="${CLUObject.getCountDelete()}" /></a></c:if><c:if test="${CLUObject.getCountDelete() eq 0}">0</c:if></td>
    <td><c:out value="${CLUObject.getCountTotal()}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**TLDR;** How to use spring:message where the key is dynamic in a jsp page.

Comment: Why is the key dynamic? That should be the part that is actually static.

Comment: @M.Deinum The key is dynamic because the list is populated from the database.

Comment: But why? If this is an edit screen, you sholdn't be using `spring:message` if it isn't you shouldn't be using dynamic keys.

Comment: @M.Deinum In this case, the name of the unit will have both an En and Fr name, so I figured using the spring message would be straight forward and easy instead of having to perform my own checks to see what the language is set for. The SM is located inside a loop of changing lengths. I also have plans on using SM on a generic drill page.

Comment: The keys shouldn't be different.

Comment: @M.Deinum The key for En/Fr will not be different, but I will have multiple keys that will be changing. So for example, key1 is Location, key 2 is position, ...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for the assistance, I figured out what the issue was, and as with some (or all) errors, one was masking others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was.

**Short Answer:** the inversion of control was causing things to happen now how I expected. I was trying to access a function or member, and it kept trying to use a get version of it. Since I did not have specifically getmember() to access the variable, it was doing strange and wrong things.

By introducing `public String getspring_name() {return spring_name;}` all of a sudden the `<spring:message code="${CLUObject.spring_name}" />` works.

**Long Answer:** In another section of my code I discovered what I thought was a private string member being accessed in a jsp page. After considerable testing of other private variable types and functions, my original thought that I was gaining access to the private member was disproved. Yet, this specific one was being accessed. After more testing I discovered when I had a get function in a very specific naming convention this behavior was reproducible. So in this case I had a private String CLU_Name, and was lucky enough to have created the get function as getCLU_Name(). Having named other get functions like getCountDelete() for Count_Delete was not allowing me to reproduce the behavior for **THEM**, because they did not fit the naming pattern.